# Getting a node in XML using fieldname in ESQL

Tags: xml, extended-sql

How to get the elements of an XML if we know the nodename.I have a sample XML like below.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE PARTS SYSTEM "parts.dtd">
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="xmlpartsstyle.css"?>
<PARTS>
   <TITLE>Computer Parts</TITLE>
<PART>
  <ITEM>Motherboard</ITEM>
  <MANUFACTURER>ASUS</MANUFACTURER>
  <MODEL>P3B-F</MODEL>
  <COST> 123.00</COST>
</PART>
<PART>
  <ITEM>Video Card</ITEM>
  <MANUFACTURER>ATI</MANUFACTURER>
  <MODEL>All-in-Wonder Pro</MODEL>
  <COST> 160.00</COST>
</PART>
<PART>
  <ITEM>Sound Card</ITEM>
  <MANUFACTURER>Creative Labs</MANUFACTURER>
  <MODEL>Sound Blaster Live</MODEL>
  <COST> 80.00</COST>
</PART>
<PART>
  <ITEMᡋ inch Monitor</ITEM>
  <MANUFACTURER>LG Electronics</MANUFACTURER>
  <MODEL> 995E</MODEL>
  <COST> 290.00</COST>
</PART>
```

I want to get all the  element in an array using esql. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
FOR part AS OutputRoot.XMLNSC.PARTS.PART[] DO
        SET item = part.ITEM;
        SET manufacturer= part.MANUFACTURER;
        SET model= part.MODEL;
        SET cost = part.COST;
        -- do what you want... 
END FOR;
```

Comment: Please extend your answer by providing reasons or explanations.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are parsing the xml on entry then you can simply just use the following:

```
SET myvar[] = InputRoot.XMLNSC.PARTS.PART[]
```